# Trying to get data from spreadsheet range, check string value, convert to number, add total amount

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google form that outputs data to a spreadsheet.

In this spreadsheet it has the data formatted as specific strings, so there is zero variance on the name of the strings.

First off, I'm trying to be able to grab the range that's inserted into the function as a parameter for use as a variable inside the function.

Second, I want the code to scrub the entire named ranged (just a column) and do a if else tree to check if cell contents matche one of the options. If it matches a specific option, add a set amount to a specified variable inside the function and restart the for loop until it reaches the end of the sheet.

Here's what I have so far.

It's jumbly, and I was just trying to piece together snippets, but I don't know how to grab attributes of the cell that's calling the function, or if you can even do that.

I could write the code based on the cell in question if I knew that.

Ignore the for loop data as without the knowledge of the cell attributes or column attribute of the named range, I have no idea how to format that.

```
function holystaffplanks(input)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0])
  var range = sh.getDataRange();
  var col = range.getColumn() ;
  var values = range.getValues();
  var amount = 0;
  for (var y = 1; y < 1000; y++)
  {
    if (input = "Holy Staff")
    {
      amount = amount + 16;
    }
    else if (input = "Life Touch Staff")
    {
      amount = amount + 16;
    }
    else if (input = "Great Holy Staff")
    {
      amount = amount + 20;
    }
    else if (input = "Fallen Staff")
    {
      amount = amount + 20;
    }
    else if (input = "Divine Staff")
    {
      amount = amount + 20;
    }
    else
    {
      amount;
    }
  }
}
```

*Yes this is from Albion Online*

Comment: So you have a column of names and want to add the modifier based on the name to amount? Is it for the whole column (because of the for loop) or just for one submission at time of submission? What do you want to do with amount once you are done? Is the function triggered on submission or how is it called?

Comment: Or is it just a mapping for a spreadsheet function? e.g. =holystaffplanks("Great Holy Staff") = 20?

Comment: It's called in a cell to output a total value.
The user fills out the form and selects their weapon of choice.
The form outputs to a spreadsheet.
The spreadsheet has a prenamed range (HolyStaff).
I want this to check the entire range (which is only a column) and compare it to the if tree above.
After it compares it to it, if it is one of the valid strings (directly copied from the form, so there is no variance), it adds a specific value based on which one it is, or none if there is an empty cell.
The function ends with the total value, which I need to return after the loop it looks like.

Comment: Just added a return amount; after the end of the for loop.

Comment: In the column it either places a blank (if they didn't pick that class of weapon), or it places a specific name that's output from a dropdown menu into a spreadsheet I called RAW DATA.

The next sheet over is a conversion sheet.
In that sheet I have it call:
    =HOLYSTAFFPLANKS(HolyStaff)
Which looks to the range as a parameter. It does reach the named range properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want something like this:

```
function holystaffplanks(input) {
  modifiers = {
    "Holy Staff": 16,
    "Life Touch Staff": 16,
    "Great Holy Staff": 20,
    "Fallen Staff": 20,
    "Divine Staff": 20
  }

  function modifier(x) {
    return modifiers[x] || 0;
  }

  function runningTotal(results, value) {
    results.push((results[results.length - 1] || 0) + value);
    return results;
  }

  if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    return input.map(modifier).reduce(runningTotal, []);
  } else {
    return modifier(input);
  }
}
```

You can call it in the spreadsheet like

- `=holystaffplanks("Holy Staff")`,
- `=holystaffplanks(A1)` or
- `=holystaffplanks(A1:A15)`

Comment: So that goes down every cell in the column and checks it against a modifier, which turns it into a number if it matches one?
I need it to also keep track of the total amount of each (each cell should add to the next).

Comment: This implementation returns a 0 if it doesn't match, but you might just as well return a blank. So you need a cumulative total down the column?

Comment: Yeah. When I called it it output 16 three times, even though I had Holy Staff in cell row 1 and Life Touch Staff in cell row 2, which is 16 and 20.
It also output 99 0's in the cells below.

Comment: I need it to ignore the very first row though too, because that's the linked titles row, and it has a name that matches exactly to the first item modifier.

Comment: Ok so now it returns the running total of modifiers. The other problem you can solve by removing the header, adding a `filter(function(_,i) {return i > 0}) `before calculating the total or  by adding an `i` parameter to modifiers that returns 0 if `i===0`.

Comment: Ok. I'll tweak it. I only want it to output the final value. This is great